# How To Use Model Of Another Application in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, model

I am working on a project where I create Two Application hosted in same site.
My structure is given below…

SITE

- SYSTEM
- APPLICATION

  - font_end
  - back_end

Now my question is,is it possible to access model of one application from another application.

As example, I have a model named ‘User_model’ in font_end application. Is it possible to use this model from back_end application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but there is a but. It doesn't matter where your files are in an absolute sense, but it is not necessarily the easiest thing in the world to accomplish.

Your best bet is to use symlinks if you can and link them into a sub-directory of your models directory. This would be simple and clean.

Barring that, you should extend Loader and overwrite the `&model` method to look in the secondary directory (perhaps reassign $path to the alternate application's model folder if `$path == 'frontend'`).

If that also isn't an option, loading is done through `APPPATH.'models/'.$path . '/' .$model.EXT`. This means you can access the model by the relative path to `APPPATH.'models/'`. Don't do that if you can possibly avoid it, however. It is non-obvious and an invitation to errors.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your last version (error prone I know) and got this result:
`Unable to locate the model you have specified: ext.`

I used this load code to access the frontend model from my backend:

`$this->load->model('APPPATH.'/models/frontend/'Frontend_Model'.'EXT');`

apppath and ext constants should be used like variables, but if I put it this way my notepad ++ highlighting goes wrong:

`$this->load->model(APPPATH.'/models/hp/'Homepage_Model'.EXT)`

Answer (score 0):

admin/application/model/accounts_model.php
application/controller/home.php

## Put this code in home.php to use model of admin applicaton

```
        $this->load->model('../../../Unicorn/application/models/accounts_model');
```