# Loading a Codeigniter model from another application

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I am trying to load a Codeigniter model from another application. I know this can be done easily with HMVC but using that technique means all modules should be in the same `/application` directory, as far as I am aware.

The folder structure I have is similar to this:

```
document_root
  - my_app/
    - application/
      - controllers/
      - models/
  - application/
    - controllers/
    - models/
```

I have a model in `/my_app/application/models/` that I want to load from a controller in `/application/controllers`. Is it possible to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky. I found another answer on SO with the possible solution:

> Your best bet is to use symlinks if you can and link them into a
>   sub-directory of your models directory. This would be simple and
>   clean.
>
> Barring that, you should extend Loader and overwrite the &model method
>   to look in the secondary directory (perhaps reassign $path to the
>   alternate application's model folder if $path == 'frontend').
>
> If that also isn't an option, loading is done through
>   APPPATH.'models/'.$path . '/' .$model.EXT. This means you can access
>   the model by the relative path to APPPATH.'models/'. Don't do that if
>   you can possibly avoid it, however. It is non-obvious and an
>   invitation to errors.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6757645/1379394